# Vb.net with mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm making window based application using vb.net and mysql as backend.

Does it require mysql to be installed on client machine to run application?

Answer (score 0):

"Mysql" consists of two parts: a server portion, and a client portion.

Yes, you must install the client portion of mySQL on your VB client.  If the MySQL server is remote, than you must also enable remote access.

Here are a couple of good tutorials:

- http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/dotnet/
- http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-1

Again, you do *not* need to install the entire MySql server on your VB.Net client.

However, you *do* need to install any MySql connectors that VB.Net needs to talk to.  You have several choices, including ODBC or MySql native.  All things being equal, I'd recommend the native MySql connector.

Comment: is it some sort of database driver?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to  install it on the  client PC and set it as Client